# Saving a single object in query result

Tags: angularjs, tastypie

I have declared an AngularJS service to work with django-tastypie server:

```
MyApp.service('AppService', [ '$rootScope', '$resource', function ($rootScope, $resource) {
    return $resource("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/app/:id/", {'delete': false}, {
        query: { method: "GET", isArray: false, params: {
            limit: 1000
        } }
    });
}]);
```

Then, following [this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource) I tried saving a single object and failed:

```
var apps = AppService.query(function() {
    // Read results
    console.log(apps.objects[0].name);      <-- OK!

    // Change and save specific item
    var app = apps[0];                      <-- Undefined!
    app.name = 'Specific App';
    app.save();
});
```

I can use the results in `apps.objects`, but `apps[0]` is undefined.

How can I save a specific item in a query result? (It seem to be possible by the [official example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource))

### Update

I was not able to solve this problem the way I wanted to. Instead I did this:

```
var _app = AppService.get({id: $scope.selected_app.id}, function () {
    _app.attribute = app.attribute;
    _app.$save();
});
```

Which is similar to sss solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can try that solution, but the best option will be get only one demanded object from your server instead of array.

var apps = AppService.query(function() {
        // Read results
        console.log(apps.objects[0].name);      <-- OK!

```
    var app = new AppService();
    angular.extend(app, apps.objects[0]);                           
    app.name = 'Specific App';
    app.$save();
});
```

Comment: Thanks sss, but the `app.$save()` in your code generates `TypeError: undefined is not a function`. Each element in apps.objects does not support $save.

Comment: @Michael try apps.$save()

Comment: Thanks sss, but `apps.$save()` will post the entire result set, while I would like to post a specific object in this set.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is explicitly saying that you don't want an array as result :

```
isArray: false
```

Comment: Thanks benek, but even when I remove this option (the default is isArray: true) the result is not an array.

Comment: In this case, the only thing can be your API that does not returns an array. Because your are using everything else correctly (query/GET/isArray:true).